# Get original path from django filefield

Tags: python, django, file, forms, field

My django app accepts two files (in this case a jad and jar combo).  Is there a way I can preserve the folders they came from?

I need this so I can check later that they came from the same path.

(And later on accept a whole load of files and be able to work out which came from the same folder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is not possible, most browsers at least firefox3.0 do not allow fullpath to be seen, so even from JavaScript side you can not get full path
If you could get full path you can send it to server, but I think you will have to be satisfied with file name

Comment: Ah - as can be seen in this answer to a related question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81180/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-html-input-form-in-firefox-3

Thats pretty annoying as I need to group these by directory.  I'm probably going to use postlet for some uploading, so might use it to solve this problem too.