# Problem with jsp type = "file"

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, file-upload

I have a problem with a JSP page.
I have a type = "file".

```
<h4>Link:<input type="file" name="linkFile" value=""/></h4>
```

When in my servlet call the istruction:

```
System.out.printf(request.getParameter("linkFile"));
```

the return string is the name of the File and not the path.

There is a way to get a path and not only a file name.

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to get the file path from html input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81180/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-html-input-form-in-firefox-3) To the point: you shouldn't be interested in the file path, but in the file content. Use Apache Commons FileUpload.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's browser-dependent, some browsers send the whole path, some don't.

The file path is irrelevant in the server side anyway. If you want to upload a file, you should use `multipart/form-data` and the related functions.