# <input type="file"> reads only file name not full path

Tags: jquery, html, glassfish, servlets

I am using Glassfish Server.I have seen the apache file upload to solve it...but i want to implement it in glassfish server.

image.html

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select a file:
    <input type="file" name="first" id="first" />
    <br />
    <input type="button" name="button" value="upload" id="button" />
    <p id="test"></p>
   <img src='Unknown.png'  id="profile_img" height="200px" width="150px" />
</form>
```

test.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var filepath= $("#first");
    $('#button').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type:       "post",
            url:        "imageservlet",
            data:       "user="+filepath.val(),
            success:    function(msg) {
                            $("#profile_img").attr('src',msg);
                            $("#test").html(msg).fadeIn("fast");
                        }
        });
    });
});
```

imageservlet.java

```
String user=request.getParameter("user");
out.print(user);
```

the output is file name not full path.

Comment: This is browser specific. Related: [How to get full file path in Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81180/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-html-input-form-in-firefox-3/3374408#3374408)

Comment: can to  do give me example to do server side coding in jsp.but I am using glassfish not apache server.

Comment: That link was not for decoration :) Click and read it. It contains in turn another links as well.

Answer (score 3):

Browsers handle this differently. Not all browsers will let you access the full path name (which makes perfect sense from a security standpoint).

Comment: It also makes perfect sense from a "This control is designed to upload a file" standpoint. It isn't a tool to describe where a file exists on the client's hard disk. That information is useless in the context of the WWW.