# File upload problem using Apache commans File upload API in JSP/Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

im trying to upload a file using org.apache.commons.fileupload. but i dont no, what mistake i have made im getting the following error in my servlet. please any one help me on this..this is the error im getting.

```
     javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception


 root cause 

 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream
org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory.createItem(DiskFileItemFactory.java:199)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:361)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
upload1.doPost(upload1.java:34)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

this is my servlet code

```
   if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req)) {

         // Create a factory for disk-based file items
         FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

         // Create a new file upload handler
         ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

         // Parse the request
         try {
             List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(req);
             for (FileItem item : items) {
                 // process only file upload - discard other form item types
                 if (item.isFormField()) continue;

                 String fileName = item.getName();
                 // get only the file name not whole path
                 if (fileName != null) {
                    // fileName = FilenameUtils. getName(fileName);
                 }


             }
         } catch (Exception e) {
             res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                     "An error occurred while creating the file : " + e.getMessage());
         }

     } else {
         res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE,
                         "Request contents type is not supported by the servlet.");
     }
```

and form

```
          <form method="POST" action="upload1" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream

It is just telling you that the mentioned class is missing in the runtime classpath. As the package name hints, it's part of Apache Commons IO. You can [download](http://apache.cs.utah.edu//commons/io/binaries/commons-io-2.0.1-bin.zip) it from http://commons.apache.org/io. Extract the downloaded zip, put the JAR file in `/WEB-INF/lib`, rebuild/redeploy/restart the webapp/server and this error should disappear.

Comment: Hi thank u very much BalusC .. sorry for asking such a stupid question. i forgot to add commons IO jar on my class path...but another problem is im printing the file name but it is not showing the full path name.

Comment: No problem. Hope you've at least learnt how to interpret exceptions. As to the filename, the full path should be **not** of your interest. Even more, you are [supposed](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/faq.html#whole-path-from-IE) to trim it off using `FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName())` because the buggy MSIE browser sends the full path along! The path is useless. Just get the file content as `InputStream` by `item.getInputStream()`. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81180/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-html-input-form-in-firefox-3/3374408#3374408).