# File upload in jsp

Tags: eclipse, jsp, ubuntu-10.10, tomcat

I want to upload any type of file(one file at a time) but i am facing the problem my **html form is returning only source filename not path.
my html file:
    
    
    
    
    
    **Select a file to upload :**

```
FileUpload.jsp :-

<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.io.*"%>

<%
String path=request.getParameter("filename");
System.out.println(path);
String newPath="";
int count=0;

if(path!=null)
{
String arr[]=new String[100];
StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(path,"/");
while(st.hasMoreTokens())
{
    arr[count]=st.nextToken();
count++;
}
// create ur own path

newPath="/home/saurabh/"+arr[count-1];
int c;
try{
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(path);
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(newPath);
while((c=fis.read())!=-1)
{
fos.write((char)c);
}
}
catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
out.println("Thanks for using");
out.println("<br>");
out.println("<br>");
out.println("1.File1 Uploaded from :: "+path);
out.println("<br>");
out.println("<br>");
out.println("2.Uploaded File1 is Saved in :: "+newPath);
%>
```

Comment: This code looks spooky, have you had a look on commons fileupload?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81180/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-html-input-form-in-firefox-3/3374408#3374408

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> html form is returning only source filename not path

You do not need  to know file path for uploading a file.

You have to change/add `enctype="multipart/formdata"` in your form tag. This way you can access file no need to get file path.

Also look at [apache commons fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/).