# How to get full path using <input id="file" name="file" type="file" size="60" > in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, filepath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the file path from HTML input form in Firefox 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81180/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-html-input-form-in-firefox-3)

```
 <input id="file" name="file" type="file" size="60" >
 <input type="Submit" value="Generate XML" >
```

I don't want to upload that file!!
I need to pass the browsed file from The JSP file to the servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and the paste these two input fields.

```
<input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" />
<input type="text" name="fileName" id="fileName" value="" />
```

Below the fields paste this jquery. NOTE: Not forget to include the jquery file.

```
$("#upload").change(function () {
  var filename = $(this).val();
  $('#fileName').val(filename);
}).change();
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a `hidden input` field and save the file name on that field and remove the file from the `file input` via Javascript.

for example.

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="hd1" id="hdFile"/>
<input id="file" name="file" type="file" size="60" />
<input type="Submit" value="Generate XML" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
var filePath = document.getElementById('file').value;
document.getElementById('hdFile').value = filePath;
document.getElementById('file').value = '';
```

Comment: var filePath = document.getElementById('file').value;
 For the id "file" in the above line its showing invalid constant...

Comment: var filePath = document.getElementById('file').value;
alert(filepath); But the filepath shows the name of the file not the path......I want full path.....Can somebody please get me out of it!!!!

Comment: You can't. For security purposes, the browser will never post the full file's path. The reason for this is that the path is only relative to the client computer and once the file is uploaded to the server it is no longer relevant. You can't depend on knowing the file structure of the client machine, as it may change without you knowing, which would then break your code. You will need some other method of determining what action to perform.

Comment: Useless Answer you wasted my time..