# My inputStream is always empty

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i'm trying to develop a form to upload images and insert them into a blob field of a db.
I'm following this guide http://www.codejava.net/coding/upload-files-to-database-servlet-jsp-mysql

This is my form

```
<form method="post" action="FileUploadDBServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="FormNews" name="FormNews">
<input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" size="50"/>
<input type="submit" value="Procedi">
</form>
/////////////// FileUploadDBServlet is a servlet
```

when i try to get what was in the field "photo" this way

```
 Part filePart = request.getPart("photo");
```

i always have a null; filePart  is always null.

Dunno where i'm making a mistake.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HttpServletRequest#getParts() returns an empty list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445296/httpservletrequestgetparts-returns-an-empty-list) That answer can help you

Comment: I suggest `Apache Commons:File Upload`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to annotate your servlet with:

```
 @MultipartConfig
```

to enable support for parsing `multipart/form-data` requests.
Otherwise the request's content will be always `null`.

Example:

```
@WebServlet(description="descriptionHere", urlPatterns={"/urlPatternsHere"}
@MultipartConfig
public class Upload extends HttpServlet {
// some code here
}
```

Then you can use:

```
Part filePart = request.getPart("photo");
```

And retrieve your request content.

Comment: i was missing @MultipartConfig. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

the correct way should be

```
request.getParameter("photo");
```

Comment: Even if i try to use request.getParameter on a type=text i always have null.
It seems my servlet can't get information from the form

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : set

```
enctype='multipart/form-data'
```

like

```
<form id="some_form" name="some_form_name" enctype='multipart/form-data' >
</form>
```

in your form

step 2 : in your controller/servlet/JSP

```
Byte[] photo_param = request.getParameter("photo");
```

Step 3 : store this byte array in your DB , where column datatype="blob"