# Is there a browse button in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf

I need this for the import functionality of the web-based app im creating. I need to get the path of a text file the user wants to be imported in order to egt the data inside the text file and saves it in a database.

Comment: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSingle.jsf

Go for it, its very simple....

Comment: how do import the LoggerFactory?

Comment: Well, a simple answer is: Remove all the logger related statements, they are just used to print some debugging lines. They are not required for file upload.

Comment: You do **not** want to get the path of the file. You want go get the **contents** of the file. Read this thoroughly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81180/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-html-input-form-in-firefox-3/3374408#3374408

Answer (score 3):

There is no such component in standard JSF. However, there are several component libraries that offer file selection:

- [PrimeFaces `<p:fileUpload>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadHome.jsf)
- [RichFaces `<rich:fileUpload>`](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=fileUpload&skin=blueSky)
- [IceFaces `<ice:inputFile>`](http://component-showcase.icefaces.org/component-showcase/showcase.iface)
- [Tomahawk `<t:inputFileUpload>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_inputFileUpload.html)
- etc. - basically every JSF component framework has such a component

Answer (score 0):

You could check this out - http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/fileUpload.jsf, and build yours accordingly.