# Asp.net mvc - get full file name of uploaded file

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

Is it possible to get full file name of uploaded file in asp.net mvc?

**UPDATE**
The data contains only the file name, but doesn't the file path! See the attached image for details.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you mean the full file path?  Or just the file name?

Comment: @Scott Rippey, full file name.

Comment: Oh, ok.  Just to clarify though, what do you consider a "full file name"?  "C:\Path\To\My File.txt", or "My File.txt"?

Comment: You're making a major conceptual mistake. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81180/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-html-input-form-in-firefox-3/3374408#3374408

Answer (score 9):

It depends on the browser.
Most browsers (FF, Chrome, Safari) do not send this information, primarily for security reasons.  However, it appears as though some versions of IE do send the full client path.
This value will be stored in the `FileName` property of the `HttpPostedFile`.

[The documentation for `FileName` should help.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.filename.aspx)  It says:

> FileName: The name of the client's file, including the directory path.

In the following code, `postedFile.FileName` will vary based on the browser.  Therefore, it's important to always extract just the filename, and you might also get lucky and get the `clientPath` too.

```
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFile postedFile) {
    var clientPath = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(postedFile.FileName);
    var filename = IO.Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
    ... Save the file, etc ...
}
```

Comment: have a look please at the my attach.