# Asp.net mvc - get full file name of uploaded file - part 2

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I ask about it  here - [Asp.net mvc - get full file name of uploaded file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976998/asp-net-mvc-get-full-file-name-of-uploaded-file) but they understood me wrong. Therefore I ask again.

Is it possible to get full file name of uploaded file in asp.net mvc?! For example, `"C:\path\path2\fileName3.txt"`. I need to get  `"C:\path\path2\fileName3.txt"`.  I think it's impossible.

See this image for details.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp.net mvc - get full file name of uploaded file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976998/asp-net-mvc-get-full-file-name-of-uploaded-file)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the browser. For some browser (like FF) sending to much information to the server is a security breach. You can read more [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/ashicmahtab/archive/2009/05/20/fileupload-control-doesn-t-give-full-path-help.aspx).

Comment: Is there a cross browser method to do it?