# Uploading file from Struts/JSP into PostgreSQL large objects ("lo"/"oid") in the DB

Tags: java, jsp, postgresql, struts

I have an application that uses PostgreSQL, JSP and the STRUTS Framework

I want to insert a file into a table in PostgreSQL using the OID type, so it's stored as a large object in the database.

My table definition is this one:

```
CREATE TABLE mensaje
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  file oid,
  CONSTRAINT pk_mensaje PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=TRUE
);
ALTER TABLE mensaje
 OWNER TO postgres;
```

Anybody know an example of how the `Action`, the `ActionForm` and the `.jsp` should be?

If not, is there any other example that explains how to do it without using the OID type?

Comment: There are three ways to store files in PostgreSQL: (a) with the oid type as references to `pg_largeobject`, [preferably using the `lo` contrib module to manage them](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/lo.html); (b) as `bytea` values in table columns, preferably only for smaller files; (c) externally on the file system, storing only the file names in the database. See this prior answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11929369/398670

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a two step process to solve the problem:

1. [File upload using Struts 2](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/file-upload.html)
2. [PostgreSQL Java tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/postgresqljavatutorial/), check the *Writing images* section.

Additional note: Once the file has been received in your Action, you should use the byte array data to save it in your `OID` field.

---

From your comment, this should be the way in Struts 1.x

In the JSP

```
<html:form action="fileUploadAction" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File : <html:file property="upload" /> 
    <br />
    <html:submit />
</html:form>
```

In your action class

```
YourForm uploadForm = (YourForm) form;
FormFile file = null;
try {
    file = uploadForm.getFile();
    //FormFile#getFileData() returns the byte array containing the file data
    //You can use it to save the file in your database and other things you want/need
    int id = 9001; //assuming this is a valid id in the mensaje table
    MensajeService mensajeService = new MensajeService();
    mensajeService.saveFile(id, file.getFileData());
} catch (Exception e) {
    //log the errors for maintenance purposes (bugs, fixes, etc) 
}
```

The `MensajeService` class will connect to your Postgre database and save the file

```
public class MensajeService {

    public MensajeService() {
    }

    public void saveFile(int id, byte[] fileData) throws SQLException {
        //this is a very simple skeleton, you have to adapt this to 
        //your needs, the way you're connecting to dabatase, etc...
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        try {
            con = ... //get the connection to your postgre db

            //Initialize a new transaction
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            // Get the Large Object Manager to perform operations with
            LargeObjectManager lobj = ((org.postgresql.PGConnection)conn)
                .getLargeObjectAPI();
            // Create a new large object
            int oid = lobj.create(LargeObjectManager.READ | LargeObjectManager.WRITE);
            // Open the large object for writing
            LargeObject obj = lobj.open(oid, LargeObjectManager.WRITE);
            //in the provided example, the code shows a way to get the byte array data
            //from the file (using the File and FileInputStream classes)
            //you don't need all that because you already have the byte array (good!)
            //so you only write the binary data in your LargeObject (OID) object
            obj.write(fileData);

            //creating the SQL statement to insert the OID
            String sql = "INSERT INTO mensaje VALUES (?, ?)";
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.setInt(1, id);
            ps.setInt(2, oid);
            //
            pstmt.setBinaryStream(2, fin, (int) img.length());
            //saving the file
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            //closing the transaction successfully
            con.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //error in the transaction, start a rollback
            if (con != null) {
                con.rollback();
            }
            throw e;
        } finally {
            //don't forget to free the resources after using them
            pstmt.close();
            con.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Struts 1 code adapted from: [Uploading a file in struts1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8255244/1065197).

PostreSQL code adapted from [here](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/binary-data.html).

Comment: Sorry, i edited the tags. Does this work with Struts 1 as well?