# Finding path of chosen file in Django FileField

Tags: django, filefield

I am using a forms.FileField to have the user choose file to open.  I need to know which path the user chose in addition to the filename.  I can't seem to find that anyplace.  I will be loading other files from the same path.

Answer (score 2):

The path on the client (the user's computer) is not sent.

You cannot load files from the same path - unless you have some client side code (like a java applet or flash application) that has proper security permissions to open files on the client's computer, then send the files to your server over a TCP connection - which you don't.

So in summary, the file path on the client's computer is not available when using file upload fields, using any server side language.

For more information:

1. [RFC 2388](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2388.html) (the specification)
2. [How to get the file path from html input form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81180/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-html-input-form-in-firefox-3)
3. [W3C Form Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2)