# reading from a file using the input type=file in grails

Tags: grails, file-upload, groovy, file-read

Hi I have the following code in my grails gsp

```
<form action="upload-script-url" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table class="table"style="width: 75%">
      <tr>
        <td>
            <span  style="font-weight: bold; ">Select the Source File:</span>
            <input size="75" type="file" id="payload" name="payload"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="submit" class="red" id="Run">Run</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

I read the form parameters from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81180/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-html-input-form-in-firefox-3)

Are those right parameters in the html form?

Now how should I proceed to read the data from the selected file? do I have to use the apache commons fileupload api ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grails file upload tutorials?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030142/grails-file-upload-tutorials) + [many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[grails]+upload)

Comment: Very severe lack of search skills. This is answered on SO and in the actual Grails documentation (as stated above and below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
request.getFile("payload")
```

and you will get a [CommonsMultipartFile](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartFile.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you take some time to (again) actually [look at the documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#6.1.9%20Uploading%20Files) you will see how to do it...

Comment: -1 why bother with documentation when he can get you to read it for him and highlight the relevant sections?

Comment: most of pri_dev's questions are able to be easily answered by looking at the docs.