# check for null for tag <input name="file" />

Tags: servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)

I have a jsp with input tag with its name attribute as "file" through which i am uploading a photo to the database. While updating information,sometimes i don't want to upload a new photo. In that case i have to check for null in my servlet. I tried this

```
 [...]
```

### servlet :

```
if(request.getParameter("file")!=null)

   String imagePath=request.getParameter("file");
```

[...]

but this does not work. Can anybody suggest a solution?

Comment: when i use <input type="file" name="file" /> in my jsp,i dont not upload  any files. but der are few other fields to be updated.there is no need for me to upload a new photo. What will request.getParameter("file") contain when i don choose any file??

Comment: I suggest to read this answer as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81180/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-html-input-form-in-firefox-3/3374408#3374408

Comment: sorry. it dint help me for the way i wanted. I am able to upload a photo,retreive and display it.All i want to know is the content of request.getParameter("file") when no file is chosen. i searched everywhere and dint find a solution. Thank you

Comment: As both links are trying to explain you, using `request.getParameter()` for file fields is wrong in first place.

Comment: When i upload a new photo,and use request.getParameter() i am getting the exact path name of my file..and i am able to upload it correctly.Why wont it work for null checks?

Comment: I'm crying right now, but I've posted a generic answer anyway.

Comment: okay thank you.. as i am new to jsp and servlets i need some time understanding that. Anyway thank you for your help. And dont cry !!

Comment: I'm not sure how to make the both linked answers more clear. Sure that you did thoroughly read them, or did you just scan for code snippets which look similar yours? The concrete problem is not specific to JSP/Servlets, but much more basic, the basic web development and HTTP concepts.

Comment: i went thru it which is when i realised that it only works when both browser and server are in same machine.. Anyway thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The `null` check works only if a field is not submitted at all. However, submitting an empty field is not the same as not submitting a field. Fields which are not filled out, but submitted, end up as empty strings. So you want to perform an additional check if the value is not just an empty string.

In other words:

```
String fieldname = request.getParameter("fieldname");

if (fieldname != null && !fieldname.isEmpty()) {
    // It's submitted *and* filled out.
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you've a severe problem with this approach of grabbing the uploaded file. This approach works only when both the webserver and webbrowser happen to run at *physically the same* machine. Take time to *carefully* go through the both links:

- [How to get the file path from HTML input form in Firefox 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81180/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-html-input-form-in-firefox-3/3374408#3374408)
- [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)

When grabbing the uploaded file the *right* way, it doesn't arrive in flavor of a `String`, so doing an empty-string-check is unnecessary.