# Allow user to select and play audio or video file on browser

Tags: javascript, html, audio, input

i want to allow user to select an audio file and play it on browser. first, i use file input to get the audio file data

```
<input type='file'/>
```

let say X represent that input, so if user select a file, i can get the file data from X.files

then, i want to send the data to this tag

```
<audio ...></audio>
```

and provide the UI to allow user to control the audio

How can i do this thing WITHOUT go through server?

Answer (score 0):

**You can't do this without going through a server!**

Please check this:

> [How to get the file path from HTML input form in Firefox 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81180/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-html-input-form-in-firefox-3)

---

`"<input type="file" />"` Is most notably used for uploading files on a remote server.

If you wish to create a web site where users can play their uploaded music or view their videos, you should consider using some Server-Side technologies to achive file uploading.

You can start with one of the following:

- [PHP](http://www.php.net/)
- [Python](http://www.python.org/)
- [Ruby On Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/)
- [ASP.NET / Microsoft Web Technologies](http://www.asp.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Store the audio file in the server that you are selecting and uploading using

`<input type-"file">` tag.

during that process keep the path of that audio for your reference and give that path to your audio tag to play it.

Hope that helps.