# How to read path to file with button in JSP/Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to read path to file from button in JSP but i have not idea how. I use multiple in JSP, maybe is a better option? I must open file and get his path.

Any suggestion how to send a path with file to function in servlet?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrED4.png]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the send the local system file path to the servlet? I don't understand the purpose of knowing the absolute client side file location

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580632/sending-file-from-jsp-to-servlet

Comment: Yes, i want to get path from file in local system and send to the servlet..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81180/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-html-input-form-in-firefox-3/3374408#3374408