# How to upload a text file in jsp

Tags: jsp, file-upload

I am trying to upload a **text** file from client machine to server. Below is the code I am using in jsp.

```
<tr>
             <td class="FORMLABEL" nowrap valign=middle>
              &nbsp;&nbsp;<%= fileLabel %>&nbsp;
             </td>
             <td class="FORMELEMENT" nowrap valign=middle>
              <input  size = "50" name="loadFile" type="FILE" >
             </td>
     </tr>
```

I have checked the content Type of the load file, it is **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** 
I need to read the file. How can I **copy this file from client machine to the server** using JSP?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a servlet for `fileupload`

Create a form there and submit to server

```
<form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="description" />
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and in servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                  throws ServletException, IOException {
    try { 

--- - - -

-----
```

Do as shown in [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)

```
}
```

and also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81180/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-html-input-form-in-firefox-3/3374408#3374408) for more info and possibilities.