# Open file dialog window in jsf

Tags: java, jsf-2

I am new to learning JSF. I want to export excel file data into database.For this task i am using APACHE-POI framework.And i want to open Excel file  when i click OPEN EXCEL button,then i want to open "open dialog" for fetch a document and filepath(i.e where i opened a file).Please help me to solve my problem.

Thank you.

Comment: i want Excel file path i.e which directory my file is located through open dialog

Comment: You cannot put a 'preferred' local folder in the client-side open file dialog. That would be a 'security' risk. And the client-side location is not propagated to the server. Just the filename.

Comment: That part is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/81180